# Проверка устройства на наличие интернета

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста.
У меня есть код

```
    private boolean getInternet(Context context) {
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            status = true;
        } else {
            netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                status = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Я его передаю в другой метод, ну и рисую на свой Activity есть ли у меня доступ к интернету или нет.
Но я не могу понять как мне менять это состояние динамично? Я думаю, что можно как-то проверять кнопку вкл/выкл интернета, но как к ней обратиться? если такое возможно, то подскажите куда копать ну или ссылку на ресурс где можно почитать про это.

Спасибо!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678314/5674568 - похоже то что вам нужно

Comment: @Komdosh возможно, почитаю сейчас, спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out - думаю здесь вы найдете подходящее решение